# Can I populate an array from data saved in UserDefaults?

Tags: arrays, swift, userdefaults

Can I populate an array from data saved in UserDefaults?  This is my first app project and I had someone much more knowledgeable build the prototype and I am trying to make a couple revisions before share it with a few others for further field testing.

The app refers to a single source/list of players.  Currently, these names come from an array (possibly a dictionary?) that is currently hard coded so to speak in a swift file, so they can’t be changed by the app user.

Instead of having this list of names built-in to the app, I want the app user to be able to enter their own list of names, and then save them.

I found a method online to create a table view and add/edit/save the data using UserDefaults; can I have the app look here for these names instead?

Currently where the player names are defined

`````
class Team {
    var roster: [Player]! = [Player]()
        var name: String?
        var teamColor: Color!

    static func createTestTeam() -> Team {
        let theTeam = Team()
        //Do some stuff
        theTeam.name = "StrikeForce"
        theTeam.roster.append(Player(firstName: "player"))
            theTeam.roster.append(Player(firstName: "player1"))
            theTeam.roster.append(Player(firstName: "player2"))
            theTeam.roster.append(Player(firstName: "player3"))
            theTeam.roster.append(Player(firstName: "player4"))
            theTeam.roster.append(Player(firstName: "player5"))
            theTeam.roster.append(Player(firstName: "player6"))

        return theTeam
    }
}

````
Here also is the Player class...

````
class Player {
    var firstName: String!

    init(firstName: String!) {
        self.firstName = firstName
    }

    init(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
        firstName = dictionary["firstName"] as! String
    }

    func dictionaryRepresentation() -> NSDictionary {
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict["firstName"] = firstName
        return dict
    }
}
`````